# Wordpress get Custom Post by Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom post and Custom Taxonomy

I need to search post using taxonomy

used this code but result is null

```
$properties = new WP_Query( 
    array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 
            'orderby' => 'ID',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_type' => 'real-property',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'tenure',
                            'terms' => 'val',
                            'field' => 'slug'
                            )
                        ),                                                  
            ) 

        );
```

Comment: check your slug of both post type and taxonomy. Is it as you have entered  the given one , double check it

Comment: Thank For Reply                                                                                         Yes I checked                                                                                  
Everything is right i also tried by passing term id

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself: issue is WP_Query() function passed valued in array

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'real-property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'tenure',
                    'terms' => 'val',
                    'field' => 'slug'
                    )
                ),                                                  
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

      the_title();

   endwhile;

      wp_reset_postdata();

else :
   esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched.' );
endif; 
?>
```